# Remebering bell numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, generating-functions, bell-numbers

I read about Bell numbers and I'm looking for a way to generate these numbers quickly for tests and exams. I know there is a recursively relation but it is not useful for big numbers .

Comment: See whether this helps you: http://fredrikj.net/blog/2015/08/computing-bell-numbers/

Comment: @Rohan Shoot, I just used the information in that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate them rapidly by using the [bell triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_triangle).

Comment: Okay , thank you but do you know any algebraically way ?

Comment: what do you mean "algebraically way"?

Comment: My mean is a formula

Comment: A closed formula for the bell numbers is not known.

Comment: Therefore there is no sequence like arithmetic or geometric so that represents bell numbers . Is it true ? But in the bell triangle we can calculate it easily . It's weird!

Comment: well, the bell triangle has coplexity $\mathcal O (n^2)$, but the calculations are easier for a human than the recursive solution without it.

Answer (score 1):

> The exponential generating function of the Bell numbers is $e^{e^{x}-1}$, that is, the coefficient of $x^n/n! $ in the power series expansion of $e^{e^{x}-1}$ is the number of partitions of a set of $n $ elements.

You would like to see [Section 1.6 in Generating Functionology by Herbert.S.Wilf](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=XOPMBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=easy+way+to+remember+bell+numbers&source=bl&ots=TkdcZgRzQe&sig=BAvfFscWNigj7RNDNFvBH-oy_CQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8-pG-laTSAhVMNo8KHWu2DwMQ6AEIXTAH#v=onepage&q=easy%20way%20to%20remember%20bell%20numbers&f=false) for more information. Hope it helps.

Comment: but can you use this to generate them by hand?

Comment: Doesn't this imply that the $n$-th derivative of $e^{e^x-1}$ is $B_{n}$? at $x=0$.